# Use of containers for server side

Tags: php, docker, server, containers, cgi

I am a newbie and trying to create a CGI server. The server will get request from different clients (the server will have to open chrome and do something, so different chrome profiles for every client). I will receive requests using PHP. What is the best practice to do so? Is docker to be used in this case?

Comment: Not sure if there is a *best practice*, different companies may have different preferences as to how they manage their application stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was stated in the comment, there are lots of possibilities and the best practice could vary quite a bit by company, architecture, and tech stack.

But all things being equal, I can say that this *is* typically a good use case for Docker.  And it'd be a good place to start.

Other options:

- Going with a non-containerized approach... Run the CGI server directly on a host (could be physical for virtual).  One tradoff here is that the host's environment must be configured to support the server vs. the just the container's environment.
- Doubling down on a containerzied approach... If you plan on running multiple workloads across different containers (i.e. beyond a single CGI server), you may look at utilizing a container orchestrator, the defacto being Kubernetes.